# retrieve post data and insert it in seperate static html page without Wordpress

Tags: php, posts, static-website

I have a blog which runs on Wordpress and inside the Wordpress environment I'm fine and know how to display specific blogposts etc.

But beside I want to insert specific Blog-posts in a static HTML Website which doesn't have a CMS and is standalone.
Imagine the simplest case of

```
<body>
 <p class="blogpost"> <!-- insert specific blogpost of my blog on static website --> </p>
</body>
```

is there any possible chance to retrieve a blogpost of Wordpress by PHP without running the site on Wordpress?

Any clue how to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin.

It has endpoints for latest posts etc that can be accessed via jQuery, I use it to power mobile apps that use WordPress for content management. You also have the ability to create your own endpoints if the defaults don't give you what you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **XML-RPC** which is supported by Wordpress.

You can use RSS if you just want to read the latest posts and it will be easiest to implemented.

Both solution needs PHP so a static HTML Website won't be possible. But yes you will not have a CMS and it will be standalone.

More here :

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

and good tutorials :

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/xml-rpc-in-wordpress--wp-25467
http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-is-rss-how-to-use-rss-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about something as simple as an `<iframe>` -- If the information on the target page remains static you can just point the iframe to target that page.

There's an example on how to do this here:
http://www.dimpost.com/2012/12/iframe-how-to-display-specific-part-of.html

(in case of broken link)

```
<div style="border: 3px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -185px; height: 859px; margin-top: -533px; width: 926px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

You then position the frame using the iframe margins...

Comment: but then I can't manipulate any styles, which wouldnt be what I want to.